# Is ActivityRecognitionApi or ActivityRecognitionClient deprecated?

Tags: android, google-play-services, android-sdk-manager, activity-recognition

In the Google APIs guide, it says [ActivityRecognitionApi](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionApi) is deprecated. [15 Oct 2017]
[image]

So, I tried to use [ActivityRecognitionClient](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionClient). When building the project following error jumps.

```
cannot find symbol import com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionClient;
```

But in the [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/package-summary), it's supposed to be there.

I'm using `com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:11.0.4`
Found out that Google have released [11.4.0](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases) also. But my SDK manager gets only 11.0.4 as the newest version. (updating to Google repository rev 58)

So, what's wrong here? is API docs are not updated? or error with SDK manager? or something else?

Answer (score 1):

The `ActivityRecognitionApi` is really deprecated. Since version **11.4.0**, the `ActivityRecognitionClient` is to be used.

**Example Use:**

```
ActivityRecognitionClient activityRecognitionClient = ActivityRecognition.getClient(context);
Task task = activityRecognitionClient.requestActivityUpdates(1000, pendingIntent);
```

For more info see the [docs](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/ActivityRecognitionClient) or [sample android app](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-play-location/blob/master/ActivityRecognition/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/location/sample/activityrecognition/MainActivity.java).

Comment: yes, I initially did that. The problem here is this error.
'cannot find symbol import com.google.android.gms.location.ActivityRecognitionClient'